# iPhone: Access Camera and Album from Web app

Tags: iphone

I want to develop a web app using html5, js. One of the feature is to launch device Camera and record video, take a picture and access photo album. Is it possible to access via web app if i develop? I saw in the forums that, it is saying not possible in some places and it is possible in some places. I would like to know, is it really possible to access directly camera and album etc. ?

Please suggest!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access phone camera using Web app, as the "Web APP" typically runs in the browser of device.

Though there are some frameworks (like Phonegap) allows you to embedd your web app into native container. With this approach and added libraries from such framework you can access some of those native API's and Device Hardware.

Comment: Thank you! If possible, Can i get some more details of accessing some resources using phonegap? So, accessing Camera and album is possible through phonegap?

Comment: I dont have the code, but you can find it from phonegap API references [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera) here

Comment: Thank you! It looks like we can support most of the device specific calls from webapp using phonegap. So, we can say, "it is possible" right?

Comment: yes, but you need to distribute the app thru App Store then. (Web App usually means a webpage loaded inside MobileSafari.app)

Comment: Hi, Sorry, i'm not getting it...What i understand is, using PhoneGap, we can develop Web app, not the native app. So, App store distribution doesn't be needed.

Comment: As I explained earlier, you can not use camera if you are creating "Web APP". That runs in Mobile Safari. If you have to access camera, you have to go for the native app. But, you can reuse the HTML5 / CSS based code (if you have generated already) if you go for "Hybrid APP".

Comment: Hi, I don't have any doubt on Web app..I clearly understood it..We can forget about pure web app...My question is again and again, i can only use native app to access device resources, so how it is possible using phonegap like frameworks..? Does it to be integrated in my native iPhone app to work it further with webview?

Comment: On quick view, it does not seems to be webview. But it provides you phonegap.js (javascript file) that you can include in your html file inside phonegap application. The javascript file is integrated with rest of phonegap framework (native part of phonegap) which provides you access to phone API or phone Hardware. For rest , you should check phonegap site, or contact phonegap

Answer (score 0):

One Possible solution is,

1. Create one app and distribute it using app store
2. using your webapp, you can connect to above app using url-scheme

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-photo-picker/

go to above link, where you can find complete code for it.