# iPhone: Access Album from Web app

Tags: iphone, html

I want to develop a web app using html5, js. One of the feature is to access photo album and upload a pic to the server. Is it possible to access via web app if i develop? I would like to know, is it really possible to access directly album etc

Comment: Looks similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029301/iphone-access-camera-and-album-from-web-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, one should have some cross platform app like Phone Gap. e.g. if your application is in Phone Gap then you can access

Comment: If your app is native app then there are no issue you can directly access the album. But, if you want to access it from web application, you need to use a cross-platform tool (like phone Gap) as you cannot access it directly.